# Wait for GPIO event on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to create a script to run a motor for a door to open and close it, which will stop when it hits the limit switches. The door is activated by a light sensor.

So far I have the code for the light sensor and motor working fine, but I am not sure where the best place is to put the "when switch top == true" stop motor.

Could anyone suggest the best place to statement or is there a function I should use?

```
while True:
        def relay( state ):
                if (state == 'Open'):
                        GPIO.output(3,False)
                else:
                        GPIO.output(3,True)
                return

        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 17)

        lcd.clear()
        lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 0)
        lcd.write_string("Temp:%dC"% temperature)

        if (GPIO.input(INPUT_PIN) == False):
                relay('Open')
                print('Open')
                lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
                lcd.write_string("Door open")
        else:
                relay('Close')
                print('Close')
                lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
                lcd.write_string("Door close")

time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: May I asked why you defined a function inside a while loop?

Comment: I moved it there when I was testing my switch code. I didn't know if you need to keep checking the switch to see if it's been pressed?

Comment: All I was referring to was that a function should *contain* a loop, not re-define the function within a loop. For example `def relay(state)` is its own standalone thing. Separately defined from all the other logic you need to do.